# How can granted Super_user permission at app level?

Tags: android, root

Any one have idea how can get super user permission at Application level ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is something you'll need to handle in your code.  Either create a global variable OR extend your application class and declare a member variable that you'll need to set and then check throughout your code.

Comment: Do u ahve any idea How can access Super User permission at app level ?

Comment: @ Any one have idea about Super User permission in android at App level?